# Как проверить отсортированы ли элементы в listBox по возрастанию по алфавиту?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Как проверить отсортированы ли элементы по возрастанию в алфавитном порядке в listBox, если элементы расположены в алфавитном порядке, то не отсортировывать, если не в алфавитном, то отсортировать?

Пробовал так

```
listBox1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString(),     System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));

int n = listBox1.Items.Count;
string[] strmas = new string[n];
for (int ixdx = 0; ixdx < n; ixdx++)
{
     strmas[ixdx] = listBox1.Items[ixdx].ToString();
}
StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.InvariantCulture;
Array.Sort(strmas, comparer);
```

Comment: Проще отсортировать безусловно, линейная сложность на отсортированном списке.

Comment: @Demon, меня совсем не радует ваш процент принятых ответов. Не буду отвечать.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте просто поставить флаг.Например, если не отсортирован `flag = false`, если отсортирован, то `flag = true`, а при сортировке установить `flag = true` и проверяйте флаг в каком-нибудь обработчике, например при активации формы и.т.д
Если я конечно правильно Вас понял.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю разобраться что к чему у Вас не составит труда

```
public bool IsSort(IEnumerable<object> list)
{
  if (list.Count() <= 1) return true;
  IComparable Ai = list.ElementAt(0) as IComparable;
  if (Ai == null) throw new Exception("Содержание листа должно быть интерфейсом IComparable");
  for (int i = 1; i < list.Count(); ++i) 
  {
    IComparable Ai_1 = list.ElementAt(i) as IComparable;
    if (Ai_1 == null) throw new Exception("Содержание листа должно быть интерфейсом IComparable");
    if (Ai.CompareTo(Ai_1) > 0) // Или "<" в зависимости от проверки возрастания или убывания
      return false;
    Ai = Ai_1;
  }
  return true;
}
```

а по факту, сортируйте и всё, я так понял на выходе Вам необходимо получить отсортированный массив. Тогда нафига проверять отсортирован ли он изначально??? Юзайте FastSort.